# Computing the characteristic polynomial without determinants

Tags: linear-algebra

Given this matrix:

$\\\
A=\left( \begin{array}{cccccccc}
3 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\\
0 & 3 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 \\\
0 & 0 & 3 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 \\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 3 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 \\\
\end{array} \right)
$

Is there any way to find the eigenvalues and/or the charactaristic polynomial without computing $\det (A-\lambda I)$? It's clear that $\det (A) = 2^8$ and  $Tr(A)=2$. This indicates that the characteristic polynomial is:

$x^8 -2x^7 + a_{6}x^6 + \ldots + a_1x -2^8$

and that $\sum \lambda _i =2$ and $\prod \lambda_i=2^8$, but that's not enough to actually determine the $\lambda _i$'s is it?

Anyone have any thoughts? Thanks!

Comment: This matrix looks structured enough that it should be possible to write down all of the eigenvectors explicitly by some inspired guessing. 

Comment: You could calculate $A^2,A^3,\dots,A^8$ and then find a linear dependence relation among $I,A,\dots,A^8$. 

Comment: Or you could compute the traces of $A$, $A^2$, ..., $A^8$ to obtain the power sums of the eigenvalues, and then use the Newton formula to express the elementary symmetric functions of the eigenvalues (which up to signs are the coefficients of the characteristic polynomial) in terms of the power sums.

Comment: You could spot that $A^8 - 2A^7 - 4A^6 + 8A^5 - 16A^4 - 32A^3 - 64A^2 + 128A + 256=0$ and then check that $1,A,A^2,\ldots,A^7$ are linearly independent, and hence that this must be the char poly.

Comment: In view of Qiaochu's observation: where did this matrix arise?

Comment: $\left( {z}^{2}-2\,z-4 \right)  \left( {z}^{6}+8\,{z}^{3}-64 \right)$

Comment: @wccanard, what do you mean by "spot"? Is there someway to derive the coeffs for the Ai just from the entries of the matrix? 


@Yemon Choi, it's difficult to explain. It has to do with the way the truth tables of certain boolean functions split. They each produce matrices of the above form of size 2^n

Comment: @Bemao: what do you mean by if there is some way to derive them. You can just do matrix-multiplication. So, certainly, there is a way. 

Comment: @quid - Sorry. Yes, there is clearly a way, you're right. I suppose I was looking for something computationally easier than matrix multiplication and then looking for a dependence relation (which is the method I presume wccanard used to find that eqn). I was hoping there would be some way of using the regular structure of the matrix to quickly derive such a relation. 

Comment: Bemao -- I just typed the matrix into my computer and asked it what the char poly was. Whatever did you think I did??